# How do I add observations to an existing data frame column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame. Let's say it looks like this:

[Input data set](https://github.com/jpmenb1/World-Cup/blob/master/column.png)

I have simulated some values and put them into a vector c(4,5,8,8). I want to add these simulated values to columns a, b and c.

I have tried `rbind` or inserting the vector into the existing data frame, but that replaced the existing values with the simulated ones, instead of adding the simulated values below the existing ones.

```
x <- data.frame("a" = c(2,3,1), "b" = c(5,1,2), "c" = c(6,4,7))
y <- c(4,5,8,8)
```

This is the output I expect to see:

[Output](https://github.com/jpmenb1/World-Cup/blob/master/column2.png)

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An option is assignment

```
n <- nrow(x)
x[n + seq_along(y), ] <- y
x
#  a b c
#1 2 5 6
#2 3 1 4
#3 1 2 7
#4 4 4 4
#5 5 5 5
#6 8 8 8
#7 8 8 8
```

---

Another option is `replicate` the 'y' and `rbind`

```
rbind(x, `colnames<-`(replicate(ncol(x), y), names(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can do:

```
  as.data.frame(sapply(x, 
               function(z) 
                 append(z,y)))
  a b c
1 2 5 6
2 3 1 4
3 1 2 7
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
6 8 8 8
7 8 8 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    x[(nrow(x)+1):(nrow(x)+length(y)),] <- y
```